# Mifare Classic 1k - Error only on Samsung S III mini GT-i8190N

Tags: nfc, rfid, mifare

Hi I'm having a problem with my app. App is working with the Mifare Classic 1k chip. 
I write some information on card with **key B**.

Problem is:
Although app is working fine on Samsung S3 (jelly 4.1.2, debug mode on, nfc on), on **Samsung S III mini GT-i8190N**(jelly 4.1.2, debug mode on, nfc on) **the same app is not working correctly**. I can read with keyA, but I **can't write with keyB**. In fact, any attempt to call `authenticateSectorWithKeyB` returns `false` causing any subsequent write requests to throw the following exception:

> 01-01 01:21:44.682: E/TAG(4392): java.io.IOException: Transceive failed
>   01-01 01:21:44.682: E/TAG(4392): at android.nfc.TransceiveResult.getResponseOrThrow(TransceiveResult.java:52)

Any idea why this is happening? Any ways of working around the problem?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find out what was causing the error? As I have a similar one with exactly the same mobile device but in my case it doesn't want to decrypt the data (same code works perfectly on a Nexus 7). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I didn't find any information about the manufacturer of the NFC chip in Samsung S3 mini. However... Maybe try to use another NFC chip (e.g. NTAG203). The Mifare Classic 1k chip is not completely NFC standard compliant and thus only working with NXP chipsets.

Comment: `MifareClassic` nfc tech is available on the phone so it should work regardless of the above. I've already exchanged a few emails with Samsung UK about this but they've been pretty much useless at providing any useful information (let alone acknowledging the problem in the first place).